# Append StumbleUpon url views with jQuery and JSON REST Method problem invalid label

Tags: jquery, json, null, label

I've read about this a lot and I just can't figure it out. It has nothing to do with MY code. I've tried to get the json data from StumbleUpon Badges. As their documents:

> The Badge API allows web site publishers to create custom StumbleUpon badges on their pages by querying information about the page which the badge sits on. This is provided through a simple REST API with output in JSON format.
>   Current Version: 1.01
>   Default Version: 1.01

and my code is:

```
    jQuery.getJSON('http://www.stumbleupon.com/services/1.01/badge.getinfo?url=http://www.narga.net/',
        function(data) {
            jQuery('.stumbleupon').html(data.encoding);
    });
```

the Firefox error console output

`Error: invalid label`
Source file: http://www.stumbleupon.com/services/1.01/badge.getinfo?url=http://www.narga.net/&c=jsonp1291473203053
`line: 1, colume: 1`
Source:
`{"result":{"url":"http://www.narga.net/","in_index":true,"publicid":"1DXaNI","views":921,"title":"Narga - Ideas and inspiration in my opinion! ","thumbnail":"http://cdn.stumble-upon.com/altmthumb/271/17122271.jpg","thumbnail_b":"http://cdn.stumb

the StumbleUpon Badge JSON output difference when I add &callback or not. If I not add &callback and add alert(data) into function (data) then the Firefox Error Console tell me the dat is null.
How can I get the views value of StumbleUpon Badges JSON then append it into

```
<a href="link" class="stumble">stumble</a>
```

---

I've tried with

```
    jQuery.getJSON('http://www.stumbleupon.com/services/1.01/badge.getinfo?url=http://www.narga.net/',  
    function(data) {
        jQuery('.stumbleupon').html(data.result.views); 
    });
```

but it's not works, I still get invalid label error

Comment: why are you doing data.encoding??? , the values are inside Source..